# md-icon not working inside a text field

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am developing an angular material website. Here I want icons before input text field and after the text field.
what I did was

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" md-whiteframe="1" layout-wrap layout-padding layout-fill class="littleWhiteFrameNoBorder" ng-cloak>
<div layout="row" flex="100">
    <md-input-container flex="40">
        <label>Search Keyword</label>
         <md-icon md-font-icon="search"></md-icon>
        <input ng-model="searchFilterCtrl.word">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-icon md-font-icon="search"></md-icon>
</div>
```

Spacing was created but I couldn't see any icons before and after text field.

Comment: Is the font library loaded  ? <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/alpha_purekar/pen/vGMdMV)   click on the dialog button you will see a form I hope it solves the issue or you can just do it this way , Just don't forget to include the stylesheet as mentioned in the comment above.

```
<md-input-container>
<label>Something</label>
<md-icon class="material-icons">search</md-icon>
<input type="text">
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it solves your problem...

```
 <md-input-container>
  <md-icon  class="md-warn md-icon-button  md-24" >highlight_off</md-icon>
  <input  type="text"  ng-model="filterText"
    placeholder="search...">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Elaborate on the changes you made so others can see how you got there.